# pip install pyinstaller fails showing SSL error

Tags: python, ssl, pip, pyinstaller

I am facing SSL error issue while installing this or any other package. Any solutions to resolve this issue?

> D:\Work Folder>pip install pyinstaller
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.6) Requirement already
> satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (41.2.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2019.4.18)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: future in
> c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from
> pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem
> confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or a proxy? Are you running an antivirus that messes with HTTPS connections?

Comment: I suppose recently some changes might have occured in organization security which I am unaware of. Is it firewall related issue?

Comment: If there as a MITM inspection device between you and the Internet that could happen. Visit `https://pypi.org/simple/pip/` using a web browser and inspect the HTTPS certificate. It should be signed by `DigiCert Inc` (look for the heading "Issued By" or "Verified By"). If there is a different name (or your organisation's name) that would do it.